# Characterization of elements in non-algebraic, finitely generated field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory

I'm in the process of self-studying Galois theory from Dummit and Foote. I'm currently reading through section 13.2, on algebraic extensions, and I'm a little confused about something.

On page 525, the authors note that, for a field $F$, and algebraic elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ over $F$, elements of $F(\alpha, \beta)$ are of the form $\sum_{\substack{i = 0, 1, \ldots, n - 1 \\ j = 0, 1, \ldots, d - 1}} a_{i, j} \alpha^i \beta^j$, where $n$ is the degree of the extension $F(\alpha)/F$, $d$ is the degree of the extension $F(\alpha, \beta)/F(\alpha)$, and each $a_{i, j}$ is an element of $F$.

Then, on the next page, they say that, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not algebraic over $F$, one must use the same construction but also "close" under inversion to describe the elements of $F(\alpha, \beta)$. This is where I'm hung up -- I'm not quite sure what that means.

To simplify things, let's assume we're dealing with a simple, non-algebraic extension $F(\alpha)/F$ (since every finitely generated extension can be obtained recursively by a series of simple extensions). I understand this to mean that every element of $F(\alpha)$ is of the form $\frac{a_0 + a_1\alpha + a_2\alpha^2 + \cdots + a_n\alpha^n}{b_0 + b_1\alpha + b_2\alpha^2 + \cdots + b_m\alpha^m}$, where each $a_i$ and $b_j$ is an element of $F$; in other words, every element of $F(\alpha)$ is the ratio of two polynomials of arbitrarily large degree in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $F$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is perfectly correct (but you have to assume that at least one $b_i$ is different from zero).